# Añadir una cifra a 3 dígitos

Tags: r, regex

Quiero poner un 0 delante de las cifras que tengan 3 dígitos.
Por ejemplo, convertir esto

```
"casa/verde/999/2016,"limon/rojo/9999/2016"
```

en esto

```
"casa/verde/0999/2016","limon/rojo/9999/2016"
```

He probado con

```
text <- c("casa/verde/999/2016","limon/rojo/9999/2016")
 
gsub( "(\\d{3}/)" ,"0\\1",  text)
```

"casa/verde/0999/2016"  "limon/rojo/9**0**999/2016"

Me mete un 0 en 9999

Tengo que indicar algo como "busca 3 cifras exactas". Pero combinando `^` y `$` no he conseguido nada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción es tratar lo siguiente, agregar un cero a aquellas "3 cifras exactas", y dejar el resto igual:

```
text <- c("casa/verde/999/2016", "limon/rojo/9999/2016", "limon/rojo/99312399/2016", "limon/rojo/111/2016")

regex <- "(?<!\\d)(\\d{3})(?!\\d)"

gsub(regex , "0\\1", text , perl = TRUE)

[1] "casa/verde/0999/2016"     "limon/rojo/9999/2016"    
[3] "limon/rojo/99312399/2016" "limon/rojo/0111/2016"
```